# Redis is taking too much time

Tags: redis

We are using Redis Server and we think it is not responding. when we hit a request on server from node then it respond in 50ms but when we hit the same request in bulk (1000 ) it takes 53 sec. that is too much so can you please explain us that what we can do to reduce the response time for 1000 request.

Comment: 50ms * 1000 is 50 seconds, so the math definitely checks out there

Comment: yeah but is there any solution to reduce this response time in redis?

Comment: looks like you do it in sequence? try parallelize it maybe?

Comment: Are you pipelining your bulk?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not using [Redis pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) and/or multiple clients connecting to Redis, each issuing a portion of the commands you're trying to execute.